# How to find out the general formula of a sequence that includes the sum of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am an electrical engineer, currently focused on designing a feedback network. I've attempted to model the engineering problem as a mathematical sequence and sought to derive a general expression for it. Despite numerous attempts, I have been unsuccessful thus far. The sequence is shown below
$$
A_n=A_{n-1}+k\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(D-A_j)
$$
Both k and D are constants. A nice guy suggested to define $$B_n:=D−A_n$$, which satisfies $$B_n=B_{n−1}−k\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(B_j)$$, however still not work.

Can some one help to guide how to find out the general expression?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the suggestion of the previous answer you will end with the hypothesis:
$$
\frac{B_n}{B_0}=\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n+r}{2r}(-k)^r.\tag1
$$

This expression can be proved as follows. It is obviously true for $n=0$. Assume that it is true for all $j\le n$, then in view of
$$\begin{align}
\frac{B_{n+1}}{B_0}&=\frac{B_n}{B_0}-k\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{B_j}{B_0}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n+r}{2r}(-k)^r-k\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{j+r}{2r}(-k)^r\tag2\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n+r}{2r}(-k)^r+\sum_{r=0}^n(-k)^{r+1}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{j+r}{2r}\tag3\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n+r}{2r}(-k)^r+\sum_{r=0}^n(-k)^{r+1}\binom{n+r+1}{2r+1}\tag4\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n+r}{2r}(-k)^r+\sum_{r=1}^{n+1}(-k)^{r}\binom{n+r}{2r-1}\tag5\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{n+1}\left[\binom{n+r}{2r}+\binom{n+r}{2r-1}\right](-k)^r\tag6\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+r+1}{2r}(-k)^r\tag7
\end{align}$$
the expression is valid also for $j=n+1$. Thus by induction the expression $(1)$ is valid for all $n\ge0$.

**Explanations**

$(2)$: induction hypothesis

$(3)$: interchange of summation in the second term

$(4)$: [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)

$(5)$: reindexing in the second sum $r+1\to r$

$(6)$: joining summation, using $\binom{n}{-1}=\binom{2n+1}{2n+2}=0$

$(7)$: standard binomial identity.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to find a general expression, it's often helpful to look at the first few terms to try to find a pattern. Working with the $B_n$ sequence, we will get

$$\begin{eqnarray} B_1 & = & B_0 - k B_0 \\
& = & (1 - k) B_0 \\
B_2 & = & B_1 - k (B_0 + B_1) \\
& = & (1 - k) B_0 - k \left(B_0 + (1 - k) B_0\right) \\
& = & (1 - k) B_0 - k (2 - k) B_0 \\
& = & (1 - 3k + k^2) B_0 \\
B_3 & = & (1 - 3k + k^2) B_0 - k(B_0 + B_1 + B_2) \\
& = & (1 - 3k + k^2) B_0 - k\left(B_0 + (1 - k)B_0 + (1 - 3k + k^2) B_0\right) \\
& = & (1 - 3k + k^2) B_0 - k(3 - 4k + k^2) B_0 \\
& = & (1 - 6k + 5 k^2 - k^3) B_0
\end{eqnarray}$$

So the pattern seems to be that $B_n = P_n(k) B_0$, where $P_n$ is a degree $n$ polynomial and you should be able to find an expression for $P_n$ in terms of $P_{n-1}$, and thence potentially to a general expression for $P_n$.

Comment: Good, I will follow this to calculate Pn

Comment: These coefficients appear to be https://oeis.org/A085478

Comment: Thanks Eric Snyder. It looks correct:)